# word for sleep-deprived frustration

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm keenly aware of the feeling - the anger or shortened fuse that comes with lack of sleep. I can't figure out a word for expressing it though... Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you can get part way there with phrases like "bleary-eyed".

Comment: "I think this is the best you'll get", said FumbleFingers ***wearily***. I don't think there are even any words specifically linking *frustration, anger, tetchiness* to ***lack of energy*** (the other common reason people get crabby being that they're ***hungry***).

Comment: Something like the neo-*portmanteau* word "hangry" (meaning hungry and therefore angry)?  I've heard that one a lot recently, but no similar coinage for tired and therefore angry.

Comment: Similarly, there's also **flustratred** meaning flustered and therefore frustrated.  Seems like there are a lot of different conditions making people angry recently...  Maybe someone should coin one for "angry because of not being able to find the apt word."

Comment: I see nothing at all wrong with your original *sleep-induced frustration*, although the inspired writer could readily come with any number of equivalent and perhaps more appealing phrases. But the hunt for "just one word" makes no sense.

Comment: I guess deep down, I was hoping for something like the recently popular 'hangry'  maybe 'slangry'?  Ok, I didn't get much sleep last night either... a little loopy today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any extant term or idiom, so here is a coinage:

**Fuming on fumes**: It's a play on "[fume](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fume)" meaning "a state of excited irritation or anger" and "[running on fumes](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/running+on+fumes)," an idiom meaning continuing forward in a state of extreme exhaustion.

> Don't test my patience, I'm *fuming on fumes* today.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps  'being **wired**' would work.

From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wired):

> Definition of *wired* in English: adjective
>
> 2 [PREDICATIVE] informal: In a nervous, tense, or edgy state:
>
> *not much sleep lately — I’m a little wired*

However, other senses may be a disincentive to use the term, it is not tied in exclusively to sleep deprivation, and 'wiredness' is not given by many dictionaries; [UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wiredness) does, restricts meaning to '[a] physical and mental condition resulting from increased time on the wired world'.

Answer (score 0):

A person who is sleep-deprived is often **short-tempered**.

Answer (score 0):

It has no semantic link to lack of sleep as such, however the word ***irritable*** is very often used to describe the short fuse that comes as a result of being underslept.

Here's an exmaple:

> These inadequate coping styles, in turn, cause underslept children more stress. Because they are **irritable**, teachers get upset with them.

<sub>[Hart. A, *Stress and Your Child* (2005)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=puuilEaokvkC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=irritable%20underslept&source=bl&ots=sUXJEra-YW&sig=WWEGJDpwJ-g8zKR7REkCGZEezWQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEh8fNiN_KAhWHORQKHTJQA8AQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=irritable%20underslept&f=false)</sub>